# Консоль браузера и консоль плагина

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Работаю  с одним сайтом используя document.getElementsByClassName(). Делается клик по кнопке на сайте и этот код с консоли браузера вызывает плагин браузера, кошелек metamask. Но у плагина отдельная  консоль devtools.

И для него нужно команды вводить там чтобы нажать например confirm.
Есть ли способ как то сделать консоль единой или переключатель какой-нибудь c консоли в консоль. Чтобы это делалось автоматически